# obj scale on hover with A-Frame Library

Tags: aframe

I am learning how to use Javascript and the A-Frame library and I am trying to change the scale of an obj model while hovering on it.

I am following the Building with Components tutorial but there is something wrong with my code and it doesn't seem to work with me.

Here is my code

```
<a-scene>
        <a-assets>
            <audio id="click-sound" src="audioclick.mp3"></audio>
            <a-asset-item id="e45-obj" src="E45.obj"></a-asset-item>
            <a-asset-item id="e45-mtl" src="E45.mtl"></a-asset-item>

            <script id="link" type="text/nunjucks">
                <a-entity class="link"
                          sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"
                          event-set__1="_event: mousedown; scale: .5 .5 .5"
                          event-set__2="_event: mouseup; scale: 0.8 0.8 0.5"
                          event-set__3="_event: mouseenter; scale: 0.8 0.8 0.5"
                          event-set__4="_event: mouseleave; scale: .5 .5 .5"></a-entity>
            </script>
        </a-assets>
        <a-entity template="src: #link">
        <a-obj-model scale=".5 .5 .5" rotation="0 -45 -45" position="0 1.5 -5" src="#e45-obj" mtl="#e45-mtl">
            <a-animation attribute="position" to="0 2.2 -5" direction="alternate" dur="2000"
                         repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
        </a-obj-model></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean? it seems you can't wrap entities with element wich has `template` attribute.

Comment: In the tutorial, a template is used for an entity to make it scalable by hovering on it. I can't do the same thing with obj-model and I don't know why.

Comment: Actually, when you attach `template` component on an element, the template will be lazy-loaded after document ready. after loading, the element will be `<a-entity template>
<a-entity class="link" event-set></a-entity>
<a-obj-model></a-obj-model>
</a-entity>`, so, the `<a-obj-model>` element doesn't have `event-set` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a-obj-model event-set__scale="_event: mouseenter; scale: 2 2 2"></a-obj-model>`

Comment: Thanks! but why can't I use template with obj like the one I use with an entity?